# How to make an executable file into a desktop application

Tags: python, executable

I recently made a simple little game using python since I'm just learning programming and computer science. I was successful in making the game and converting it into an executable file using cx freeze. The problem now is that I can't run the application unless it is in the same folder with all the other components of the file (naturally). I was wondering how I would make a desktop application of my game without having to go into the folder in which the application was located in. Its really inconvenient to send entire folders to people so they can run my game.

Hope that makes sense,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use another compiling module like [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) as one example to include all required files and use the `--onefile` option to compile it into a single executable. In `cx_freeze` you can make installers by specify the `bdist` options. e.g. for windows `python setup_file.py bdist_msi`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this. Appreciate it.